# problems on the find() method of boost::unordered_map()

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map

I have the following code:

```
typedef unsigned char tTerm;
typedef uint64_t nTerm;

boost::unordered_map<tTerm *, nTerm> map;

nTerm function(tTerm * key) {
  boost::unordered_map<tTerm *, nTerm>::iterator it = standardTerms.find(key);
    if (it != standardTerms.end()) {
      return it->second;
  }
}
```

This code compiles correctly using clang (in MacOs). However, eclipse is alerting that there is a problem in the way the find() method is called. More in particular, it alerts that find() is invoked with an incompatible argument by returing the error:

"Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: 
 boost::unordered::iterator_detail::iterator>> find(const unsigned char &) 
 boost::unordered::iterator_detail::c_iterator>,const boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node> *> find(const unsigned char &) 
 boost::unordered::iterator_detail::iterator>> find(const #10000 &, const #10001 &, const #10002 &) 
 boost::unordered::iterator_detail::c_iterator>,const boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node> *> find(const #10000 &, const #10001 &, const #10002 
 &) '"

Now all the code compiles correctly, so it might be that it's an eclipse bug. However, I might be missing something important by ignoring this message. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry. Looks correct to me. You can use pointers as keys. I think it's eclipse's fault.